# C-Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} point;

point p1;
point* p2 = malloc(sizeof(point));
```

In this code where the variables p1,p2,p1.x, and p2->x are stored in stack or heap memory?

Where the mentioned variables are stored in stack or heap memory?

Comment: Automatic variables are on the stack, the memory returned by `malloc()` is in the heap.

Comment: Aside: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: `point *p2 = malloc` isn't valid at global scope (since static storage needs constant initializers in C, unlike C++).  Is all of this supposed to be inside a function?  In an unoptimized build, mainstream C compilers use stack space for automatic storage class (non-static local vars).  In an optimized build, they might only used registers for some locals.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} point;

point p1;

void foo(void)
{
    point* p2 = malloc(sizeof(*p2));
    /* ... */
}
```

- `p1` has **static** storage duration (lifetime same as the whole program)
- `p2` has **automatic** storage duration (lifetime same as the function `foo`)
- `*p2` (object referenced by the pointer `p2`) has **allocated** storage duration (lifetime same as the whole program or until it is `free`ed)

> In this code where the variables p1,p2,p1.x, and p2->x are stored in
> stack or heap memory?
>
> Where the mentioned variables are stored in stack or heap memory?

C standard (language) does not say where those objects are stored (it is up to *implementation*) and it does not matter from the programmer's point of view. Only the **storage duration** is important for you (because you need to know how long the object lives). Do not focus on implementation details when you are learning.

C language doesn't know anything about stack or heap but the most popular implementations place

- automatic storage duration objects on the stack or in processor registers. They can be also *"optimized out"* by the compiler and not stored at all
- allocated storage duration objects on the heap
- static storage duration objects in `.bss` or `.data` sections (depending if they are initialized or not). Constant ones can be stored in `.rodata` segment

Comment: With optimization enabled, some variables can be optimized into registers, optimizing away any memory storage.  Especially locals, but possibly also file-scope `static` variables depending on how they're used.  But yes, automatic variables go on the stack if they have an address at all, in typical mainstream C implementations.  IIRC, there's an IBM mainframe that allocates "heap" space for function activation records (what are normally called "stack frames" when using a stack): [What is activation record in the context of C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50479025)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you are going too deep and too far considering the question level.

Comment: I just wanted to give an example of why this answer draws a distinction between abstract-machine concepts vs. practical asm, and why it matters to say "**most** popular implementations" instead of **all** real implementations for real CPUs, because there actually are counter-examples.  Not that it's useful or instructive to study them for people who didn't already know the answer to this question, but just to keep in mind that the simple answer doesn't apply universally.